# SQLAlchemy: how to create a relationship programmatically

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'd like to create a 1:n relationship between two tables dynamically. My DB model is mapped via SQLAlchemy but due to some special features of my application I can not use the default declarative way.

E.g.

```
class Foo(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    flag = Column(Boolean)

class Bar(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'))
    # declarative version:
    # foo = relationship(Foo)
```

So I want to add relationship named "foo" to the mapped class "Bar" **after** Bar was defined and SQLAlchemy did its job of defining a mapper etc.

**Update 2017-09-05:** Why is this necessary for me? (I thought I could omit this because I think it mostly distracts from the actual problem to solve but since there were comments abouts it...)

First of all I don't have a single database but hundreds/thousands. Data in old databases must not be altered in any way but I want a single source code to access old data (even though data structure and calculation rules change significantly).

Currently we use multiple model definitions. Later definitions extend/modify previous ones. Often we manipulate SQLAlchemy models dynamically. We try not to have code in mapped classes because we think it will be much harder ensuring correctness of that code after changing a table many times (code must work in every intermediate step).

In many cases we extend tables (mapped classes) programatically in model X after it was initially defined in model X-1. Adding columns to an existing SQLAlchemy ORM class is manageable. Now we are adding a new reference column an existing table and a `relationship()` provides a nicer Python API.

Comment: What is the reason behind that? Do you want to use like an external list of models to use while create a multiple relationships?

Comment: Just add a relationship attribute to the class then, though @krassowski is right: why do you need that?

Comment: @ilja-everilä: Can you elaborate? I need the relationship definition to be completely decoupled from the actual declaration. Basically I want to know how to manipulate SQLAlchemy's internals but I could not find the right sections in the (very good) docs and I hoped someone could save me some hours of reading SQLAlchemy source code... :-)

Comment: Here's a time saver, if I've understood you correctly: ["Attributes may be added to the class after its construction, and they will be added to the underlying `Table` and `mapper()` definitions as appropriate"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html#defining-attributes). So by "just add" I meant that you can simply bolt new relationship attrs to mapped classes after they've been defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, my question above is again a nice example of SQLAlchemy's super powers (and my limited understanding):

```
 Bar.__mapper__.add_property('foo', relationship('Foo'))
```

Likely I was unable to get this working initially because some of my surrounding code mixed adding relationships and columns. Also there is one important difference to declaring columns:

```
Column('foo', Integer)
```

For columns the first parameter can be the column name but you can not use this for relationships. `relationship('foo', 'Foo')` triggers exceptions when passing it to `.add_property()`.